# i can't pass javascript variable to servlet without submitting a form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

```js
function gameLogin() {
var usernameToPass;
console.log('Fetching information from facebool.... ');
FB.api('/me', function (response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
  //pass user name to Servlet
  usernameToPass = response.name;
  pass(usernameToPass);
});
}

function pass(name) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GameManagerServlet',
                data: {
                    username: name
                },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (name) {
                    console.log(name);
                }
            });
        }
```

so basically i have this script in my jsp using Facebook login api got username then stored in a variable, and trying to pass to my servlet by another function, because my servlet needs to receive the username when the page is loaded, i've tried some ways like by ajax, but the server side when i use request.getParameter("username"); but always got null. Could you help me to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback function like below.

```
var usernameToPass;
function gameLogin() {
console.log('Fetching information from facebool.... ');
FB.api('/me', function (response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
  //pass user name to Servlet
  usernameToPass = response.name;
  pass(callback){
      callback(usernameToPass);

  };
}

    function pass(function(name) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'GameManagerServlet',
                    data: {
                        username: name
                    },
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (successname) {
                        console.log(successname);


                    }
                });
            })
```